# cannot change GR colors in react-icons

Tags: react-icons

I found gr images cannot be changed color, do you know how to solve this problem? Thank you.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { GrAssistListening } from "react-icons/gr";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <GrAssistListening color="red" size="xlarge" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

give your icon a classname for example .icon and target it like this:

```
.icon path{
   stroke: red (your color)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of old but since there were no answers on it, it might help some other people. Unfortunately we need to go the ugly way..

```
    import React from "react";
    import "./styles.css";
    import { GrAssistListening } from "react-icons/gr";

    export default function App() {
      return (
        <div>
            {/* Workaround for GR icons coloring */}
            <style>
              {`
                svg path {
                  stroke: red
                }
                `}
            </style>
          <GrAssistListening color="red" size="xlarge" />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

icon package GR is buggy. Changing color does not work as expected. Use another package for example Md. Icons overtake color of the text.

Examples:
Style:

```
<MdLanguage  style={{color:'white'}}/>
```

TAILWIND

```
<MdLanguage  className='text-white'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the path and strock to change its color
My example
JS
`<GrLicense size={70} className={styles.icon} />`

CSS

```
.icon path {
stroke: (color);}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Using this Approch

```
  import React from "react";
  import "./styles.css";
  import { GrAssistListening } from "react-icons/gr";

  export default function App() {
    return (
      <div>
        <GrAssistListening style={{color: red, font-size: 30px}} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Go into

> node_modules\react-icons\gr\index.esm.js

Search for

> GrAssistListening

Initial code of GrAssisListening

```
export function GrAssistListening (props) { return GenIcon({"tag":"svg","attr":{"viewBox":"0 0 24 24"},"child":[{"tag":"path","attr":{"fill":"none","stroke":"#000","strokeLinecap":"round","strokeLinejoin":"round","strokeWidth":"2","d":"M11,21 C11.7572165,21.6666667 12.4238831,22 13,22 C15,22 16,21 16,19 C16,17.6666667 16.6666667,16.3333333 18,15 C19.2667508,13.7332492 20,11.9329966 20,10 C20,6.13400675 16.8659932,3 13,3 C9.13400675,3 6,6.13400675 6,10 M17,10 C17,7.790861 15.209139,6 13,6 C10.790861,6 9,7.790861 9,10 M3,20 L8,14 L9,18 L14,12"}}]})(props);
```

};

Now change or delete the stroke value then restart start server to take effect.